# Error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: theming, 8, .info

After I put a new custom theme I did in my theme folder, when I go to my website to install and apply the theme, the site just keeps returning this error:

> "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

PHP error log message:

> "Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Missing required keys (core) in themes/custom/javali/javali.info.yml in Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserDynamic->parse() (line 29 of /home/rui/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/InfoPar‌​serDynamic.php)."

Yes, I know the error is very common, but I believe I explained my specific problem well.

PS: And now when I put the theme in the folder themes folder, the site works except the admin nodes.

PROBLEM SOLVED:
I put the following lines on the .info.yml file as Neograph734 said and now everything works fine!

```
core: 8.x
version: 8.x-2.0
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove your custom theme from the theme folder? You likely have a syntax error somewhere, but it is impossible to tell...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but we cannot debug a site to which we don't have access, nor can we list all the possible causes for an error as generic as that one. If you look at the logs, you will find out PHP raised an exception, or a fatal error.

Comment: Now your error is pretty clear: `Missing required keys (core) in themes/custom/javali/javali.info.yml` So apparently you did not define the core version, or there is some other context error in `javali.info.yml`. Here is [some info on theme .info.yml files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file)